# automorphism of abelian grp. of prime power order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I had an exercise to be proved:

> Assume we have an abelian group $G$ whose order is a power of prime $p$, and $H$ is its only subgroup of order $p$ .
>
> let $\phi:G\rightarrow G$ be the homomorphism that raises all elements to the $p$ power . Then show that if $Im(\phi)$ is cyclic then $G$ must be a cyclic group.

What I tried is as follows:

[image]

Now if $Im(\phi)$ is a cycle,it means $G/H$ is a cycle.

Now the hint to the question says that consider the element $a$ ,which satisfies $<aH>=G/H$ .then try to show that $<a>=G$
But I'm unable to prove the last statement .
Kindly help with this problem.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems to me that any finite abelian $p$-group with only one subgroup of order $p$ is necessarily cyclic without any additional assumptions.

Comment: I can prove it but the proof uses the classification of finite abelian groups. This question may become nontrivial if you can't use the classification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $G/H \cong \text{im }\phi = \langle aH\rangle$, then since:

$|G/H| = p^{n-1}$, it follows that $a^{p^{n-1}}\in H$, but no lesser power is. In particular, the order of $a$ in $G$ is at least $p^{n-1}$.

Could it be that the order of $a$ is $p^{n-1}$?

Well that would mean that $(a^{p^{n-2}})^p = e$, that is $a^{p^{n-2}} \in H$, so that:

$(aH)^{p^{n-2}} = H$, contradicting the order of $aH$ in $G/H$.

(Slight caveat: one needs to prove the cases $n = 1$ and $n = 2$ separately. I urge you to do so).

We must therefore conclude that the order of $a$ is thus NOT $p^{n-1}$, and thus must be $p^n$, and $a$ is a generator for $G$, which is thus cyclic.

Comment: can you please explain me the $2^{nd}$ statement ,why we considered $|G/H|=p^{n-1}$ and then why will the order of $a$ be atleast $p^{n-1}$

Comment: For a finite quotient group we have $|G/H| = |G|/|H|$. By assumption, $|G| = p^n$ for some natural number $n$ (prime power order), and $|H| = p$. Since we also have $G/H$ is cyclic, it has a generator $aH$, and thus the SMALLEST power $k$ of $(aH)^k = a^kH$ that equals $H$ (the identity of $G/H$) is the order of $G/H$. So for $k < |G/H|$ we have $a^kH \neq H$, so $a^k \not\in H$. Since $e \in H$, this means that $a^k \neq e$, for such $k$.